# Better Solution than Evernote for Code Snippets/Examples?

Tags: javascript, syntax, editor, code-snippets, evernote

I'm learning javascript and want to create a library of example code snippets as I learn new ideas. I'm currently using evernote, but am wondering if there is a more elegant solution where I can create a reference library complete with syntax highlighting/executing the code in the browser.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Evernote as the snippets etc. is primarily from various websites. The web clipper browser plugin lets me create notes right to Evernote with highlighting (as shown on the original website) preserved. Tagging and additional comments along with sharing and the availability (between job/home/mobile in my case) is a very nice addition.

For my own snippets from IDE/editor i usually do a screenshot or if i want to preserve the copy-paste-ability i just add a text/source file to Evernote.

Comment: Sure, however, when copying the code FROM Evernote, all tabs are lost.

Answer (score 10):

Tried the Evenote Plugin for Sublime3?

http://www.sublimetext.com/3

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Evernote

You can save new notes, update existing notes, using github style markdown.

Here is an example:

[image: evernote code snippet example - created with sublime 3 evernote plugin]

Comment: I'm playing with ST2. Until using ST2 now I found it quite useful!

Comment: No syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 8):

I use

[app.gistboxapp.com](http://app.gistboxapp.com)

You need a GitHub account to login: this app connects to your Gists repository saved into Github and keeps all your code snippets. It's web based so you don't need to download anything. Everytime you save a new snippet GistboxApp will add a Gist to your Github repository.

You can label all your snippets to divide them in categories.

Hope this helps...it works fine for me

Comment: Why was this down voted? Seems like a good answer to me.

Comment: I switched from codebox to gistbox myself. I don't use it as much but thats probably because I consult my own code more often.

Comment: GistBox became [Cacher](https://www.cacher.io/).

Comment: Yes GistBox is now Cacher and became prettier as well cacher.io

Answer (score 4):

For OS X there is [Quiver](http://happenapps.com/#quiver). It is very similar to Evernote in look and feel and adds many useful code snippets related features.

> Quiver is a notebook built for programmers. It lets you easily mix text, code, Markdown and LaTeX within one note, edit code with an awesome code editor, live preview Markdown and LaTeX, and find any note instantly via the full-text search.

[image: Quiver screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I am really liking [Marxico](https://marxi.co/), so far.

With this tool, your text is still stored in Evernote, but it supports code block formatting and markdown for notes. Note: This won't actually run your code.

Comment: Great tool! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use http://tohtml.com/ and copy and paste over.

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I like and use codebox but afaik it's osx only.
http://www.shpakovski.com/codebox/

Would really like to see this become cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered perfectly, but if you use sublime text as your code editor, evernote can be a fantastic was to collect and use snippets.

Sublime text as an evernote plugin. With it you can add notes (so type your snippet in sublime text and push it to evernote from sublime text) and open your evernote notes in sublime text.

So you just add your snippets to evernote. Then search them within sublime text and use them! There is a similar plugin for gist, where you store your snippets as gists and then access them through sublime text. **But I think**, evernote is a better option as it's easier to edit and re-sort snippets.

[The evernote plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Evernote)

[The gist plugin](https://github.com/condemil/Gist)